# Excel to PowerPoint Copy/Paste Macro Inconsistently Fails

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am having a problem with a macro that copies named ranges and charts out of excel and into powerpoint.  The macro functions as intended on my computer, however when when I run the macro on a coworker's computer I get Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)'.  The problematic loop is below.

```
'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next
    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear
    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
'Change aspect ratio
myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 2 
cycle=1

For Each ch In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Meeting Metrics").ChartObjects
    'Add a slide to the Presentation
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(cycle, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
    mySlide.Select
    With mySlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = slideTitles(cycle - 1)
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 32
            .Color.RGB = RGB(237, 125, 49)
        End With
    End With

    'Check if there is a table (Excel cell range) to copy for this slide
    If Not IsMissing(copyRange(cycle - 1)) Then
        'Copy Excel Range
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Meeting Metrics").Range(copyRange(cycle - 1)).Copy
        'Paste to PowerPoint
        mySlide.Select
        mySlide.Shapes.Paste
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.count)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        'Set position
        myShape.Top = tableVertPos(cycle - 1) * 72
        myShape.Left = tableHorPos(cycle - 1) * 72
    End If

    'Copy excel chart
    ch.Select
    ch.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    'Paste to PowerPoint
    mySlide.Select
    mySlide.Shapes.Paste
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.count)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Set position

    myShape.Top = chartVertPos(cycle - 1) * 72
    myShape.Left = chartHorPos(cycle - 1) * 72

    cycle = cycle + 1
Next
```

When the error occurs, powerpoint will become unresponsive and ask to close.  The error message will pop up, and debug will take me to one of lines containing mySlide (Not always the same line).  If I try to hit the continue button, it results in Runtime error 462 since the powerpoint is closed.  When I try to step through the program on the other computer to find the problematic line, it will step through a couple lines and then run like normal until it bugs out.  However, if a throw a line break somewhere inside the loop and manually iterate it or put a message box inside the loop, the code will run fine.

I've tried inserting wait or sleep into the loop to see if this helps, but this just causes the code to halt for a few seconds before failing.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is (most likely different versions of office, or updates), but you could try the .Slides.AddSlide method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm curious though, what is the benefit of using one over the other?

Comment: I'm not real sure but: Slides.addslides:Creates a new slide, adds it to the Slides collection, and returns the slide.                          Slides.add: creates a new slide and adds it to the collection.  Maybe the add method doesn't return the slide?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in the system described as a 'run ahead' in some places. I've had some success with the following ugly workaround...

1. Create the following UglyWait subprocedure

   ```
   Sub UglyWait(Optional sec As Integer = 1)
       Dim future As Date
       future = DateAdd("s", sec, Now())
       Do While Now() < future
           DoEvents
       Loop
   End Sub
   ```
2. Place a call to UglyWait before and after any Powerpoint goto, paste, or save operations.

Application.Wait doesn't work, nor does a standard single DoEvents. This does seem to help though.